# How to make fork() fail?

Tags: linux, bash, process, perl

For a script I'm writing, it's important to properly handle a failed `fork()` (see https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2014/08/19/fork/ for the Why).

But how, without bringing my system down with processes, reliably make `fork()` fail for testing my error routines?

I tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

whoami

number_of_processes=$(ps auxf | wc -l)
number_of_processes_plus=$((number_of_processes+480))

echo "found $number_of_processes processes, setting the limit to $number_of_processes_plus"

ulimit -u $number_of_processes_plus

perl -e '
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = fork();
my $errno = $!;

print "ERRNO: $errno\n";

if($pid == -1) {
        warn "PID was -1!!! errno: >>>$errno<<<\n";
} else {
        if(defined $pid) {
                if($pid == 0) {
                        warn "Child-process\n";
                } else {
                        warn "Parent-process\n";
                }
        } else {
                warn "\$pid NOT DEFINED";
        }
}
'
```

From what I believe to understand about this, this should get the number of processes (via `ps auxf | wc -l`) and set `ulimit -u` to that + 480. The 480 is derived only from playing around until the perl process starts. If I put it below 480, I only get

```
forkfail.sh: fork: retry: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar
forkfail.sh: fork: retry: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar
forkfail.sh: fork: retry: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar
...
```

(Ressource not available.)

If I put it way above +480, it always works. With 480, it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. But I seem to not be able to make it fail reliably.

How to do that without spawning as many processes as my system allows, thus rendering it unusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### systemd

On many Linux systems you can use *cgroup-based* task limits via systemd's `TasksMax=` service property, which can be precisely aimed towards one specific command:

```
$ systemd-run --user --collect --pty -p TasksMax=1 /bin/sh
sh-5.1$ ls
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

---

### ulimit

`ulimit -u` counts only processes owned by **your UID**, so the `a` flag in `ps auxf` doesn't make much sense. But in addition to that, instead of counting just processes, on Linux it actually counts **tasks** – which can be either a standalone process or a thread.

```
$ man 2 setrlimit

RLIMIT_NPROC
              This is a limit on the number of extant process (or, more
              precisely on Linux, threads) for the real user ID of the calling 
              process. So long as the current number of processes belonging to
              this process's real user ID is greater than or equal to this
              limit, fork(2) fails with the error EAGAIN.
```

<sup>*(With the way Linux NPTL has implemented threads, they have become the main object type – processes are just "thread group leaders" and PIDs are actually "thread group IDs".)*</sup>

Right now, the difference between `your_processes + your_threads` (the correct count) and `your_processes + other_uid_processes` (the one you're using) just happens to be about 480.

To make `ps` include threads, use the `H` option. (Or the `-L` option. Or the `-T` option.)

```bash
n=$(ps uxH | wc -l)
n=$((n - 4))
   # Discount the $() subshell process; the 'ps' process;
   # the 'wc' process; and the ps header line, for a total of 4. Usually.
ulimit -n $n
```

Alternatively, because the limit is UID-based, it would be more reliable if you used `sudo` to start your test script under a dedicated UID which has no other processes running yet. You could even use a wrapper calling setuid() to randomly choose a new UID for every run (from a range which doesn't correspond to actual accounts).

Doing so would avoid race conditions where the number of tasks happens to change significantly in-between your `ps` invocation and your actual test script (for example, due to background cronjobs starting/finishing, or due to a browser waking up some tabs and suspending others).

```
$ sudo -u nobody sh -c "(ulimit -u 4; ps xH)"
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1686939 pts/1    S+     0:00 sh -c (ulimit -u 4; ps xH)
1686940 pts/1    S+     0:00 sh -c (ulimit -u 4; ps xH)
1686941 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps xH

$ sudo -u nobody sh -c "(ulimit -u 3; ps xH)"
sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```